# Training Watson Discovery with (V1) python SDK APIs does not work

Tags: python, machine-learning, ibm-watson, information-retrieval, watson-discovery

I want to use *Watson discovery V1* APIs for relevancy training. I tried the following but yet to get desired result. Describing the problem in details below:

I have a set of documents some of them contain the word `'cloud'` or `'big data'`. I want to search for the word `'hadoop'` with the `query()` api and get back those documents, but discovery query returns nothing.

Now, I want to provide the following training examples to discovery to update the relevance scores so that I get those results back (I used *query expansion* for the same task and it worked, now i am interested in *relevancy training*).

I have used the api `add_training_data()` to associate the query `'hadoop'` with the relevant documents (specified by ids, the documents that contain `'cloud'`, e.g.).

Now the training data looks like the following:

```
{
  "natural_language_query": "hadoop",
  "filter": "",
  "examples": [
    {
      "document_id": "1ad6f551-e092-4ce9-b08c-eb4f4cbc9458",
      "cross_reference": "",
      "relevance": 1,
      "created": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.674Z",
      "updated": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.716Z"
    },
    {
      "document_id": "f1d11f51-31b2-414f-b359-d5336b019575",
      "cross_reference": "",
      "relevance": 1,
      "created": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.674Z",
      "updated": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.722Z"
    },
    {
      "document_id": "5bfcea6a-c925-4db5-a490-89a9d1de8d4c",
      "cross_reference": "",
      "relevance": 1,
      "created": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.674Z",
      "updated": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.729Z"
    },
    {
      "document_id": "bf07e701-6893-428c-ab16-c5446e821291",
      "cross_reference": "",
      "relevance": 1,
      "created": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.674Z",
      "updated": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.735Z"
    },
    {
      "document_id": "75082812-5c96-4d2e-b388-821a0434ad4c",
      "cross_reference": "",
      "relevance": 1,
      "created": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.674Z",
      "updated": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.742Z"
    }
  ],
  "query_id": "cc1d3677eeafe70929aeccfb462860439f61b051",
  "created": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.677Z",
  "updated": "2020-01-30T23:16:19.677Z"
}
```

where the document ids correspond to the documents in the collection, the ones that contain the word `'cloud'`. e.g.

With the training data created, now i wanted to run the earlier query again with the query text `'hadoop'`, with the assumption that discovery would automatically train itself to get the relevant results back (since I could not find any api like `'train()'` that i was expecting).  But, even after providing the training examples, discovery query still returns nothing.

I don't have any clue what's going wrong. Some help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sandipan,

As mentioned here: [Improving result relevance with the API](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/discovery?topic=discovery-improving-result-relevance-with-the-api&_ga=2.65573420.309083399.1580757566-68753765.1578053119)

> When you provide a Discovery instance with training data, the service
>   uses machine-learning Watson techniques to find signals in your
>   content and questions. The service then **reorders** query results to
>   display the most relevant results at the top. As you add more training
>   data, the service instance becomes more accurate and sophisticated in
>   the **ordering** of results it returns.

I believe that the relevance training wont work the way you need. It only reorders.

Also, "The collection's training-data set must contain at least 49 unique training queries (that is, sets of queries and examples).". You need add more queries for training to start.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there any other that you are aware of, to train with less number of training examples with discovery?

Comment: No. I went through a situation where I had to put a number greater than 50 because my examples were not varied enough. If you find out, share!